# Show a warning dialog on commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is regarding display of warning message(preferably a dialog) on Subversion commit.

Basically what we want is that during a patch or other releases when ever a developer tries to commit any changes.

1. A warning message should be displayed stating that "currently a patch is under progress, only changes with preapproval should be committed. Do you want to continue?" This should have "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons.
2. If developer clicks on "Ok" button, changes should be committed. Otherwise commit operation should be cancelled.

Is it possible to implement such a hook on Subversion commit?

Also, how can we set some flag on a branch indicating currently there is patch is in progress on it?

Comment: Another option would be to use a *branch* for patch and release code so that you don't block developers from working (although git is much more flexible for this).

Comment: Yes, the common solution to avoid problems from "bad" commits during a release window is to branch off a release branch, and release that. Then others can work merrily on `trunk`. Is there a reason you are not doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement such a hook on svn commit?

No. you can enable|disable commit in pre-commit hook, but only in non-interactive mode

> how can we set some flag on a branch indicating currently there is patch is in progress on it?

You can use any (conventional) custom property in any (conventional) location (best place, probably - branch-root) and check value of this prperty in pre-commit hook.

Second property *may* indicate receiving of approval (plain-text property is bad idea and may be|will be easy exploited, you have to have secure way /PGP|S/MIME signing?/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot interactively work with a commit. This is because the pre-commit hook runs on the server and not the client. All you can do is give the commit a *thumbs up* or a *thumbs down*. That is, you allow it, or you don't allow it. You can send stuff to STDERR in the pre-commit hook, and that will be sent to the client, but only if the pre-commit hook fails the commit.

If you want to control commits during this patching, you need a pre-commit hook. [I have one](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that's pretty flexible. You can easily change permissions to prevent certain users from doing commits during these times and give an error message why you're rejecting that commit.

You could use something like this in the control file:

```
[group PATCH_USERS]
users = bob, ted, carol, alice

[file The 2.3 branch is currently closed due to patching. Branch will be open in 2 hours]
file = **/branch/2.3/**
access = read-only
users = @ALL

[file The 2.3 branch is currently closed due to patching. Branch will be open in 2 hours]
file = **/branch/2.3/**
access = read-write
users = @PATCH_USERS
```

With this setup, only `bob`, `ted`, `carol`, and `alice` can update the 2.3 branch. All other users will get the message that the branch is closed due to patching.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, then you can use its [client-side hook scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) for this task.

In your case, write a pre-commit hook script. Your script could check somehow the flag you've set if a patch is in progress and only then reject the commit.
You don't have to show a dialog in the script, just reject the commit. TSVN then shows a button itself named "retry without hooks" so you can circumvent the hook scripts.

[Here's](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/client-side/checkyear.js) an example of a pre-commit client hook script the TSVN project uses itself to check whether each source file has the correct cp-year in the header.